# mobile application analytics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, analytics

HI all,

so we all know "pinch media" - the "spyware" software ;)

i'm searching for some really cool analytics softwares for my iphone application.
pinch media, is the one i know, it looks really great, but we all know, the reputation of this piece of software is very bad.

i'd like to know if i can use it, or if my app then is one of this spyware apps, for users (it isnt really, i know, but users might think it is, when i use this).

are there some alternatives? other programms, with the same good analysis?

I found admob and motally.com, but pinch media/Flurry is the best one atm.

Comment: Hey Geek Could U pls guide me to start learning the basics of flurry analytics in android? Where can i find its tutorial kind of things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.lemonteam.com/downloads/iphone-solutions-matrix.pdf) is a good pdf that compares some of the main iPhone/iPod touch analytics providers

Comment: this pdf has a good overview, but is there anything else with some more meat to it?

Comment: Broken link -- if you could summarize the data, that'd be helpful to future users.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/mobileAppsTracking.html)

Comment: did not know that google analytics does also offer mobile app analysis. thanks for this hint!

Answer (score 3):

Any analytics package which reports usage statistics back to a central server (Flurry, Google Analytics, etc.) will be considered "spyware" by some users, not just Pinch Media's offering.  The really paranoid users will sniff data traffic out of your application and detect traffic from any service, no matter who provides it.

If you really care about those users who will be upset by this, give them the option to opt-out of data collection in your application's settings or when the application first starts.

Comment: yes, thats a good advice. i'll add a button in my options view, to deactivate analysis, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for more inside on your app, you should try [heatma.ps](https://heatma.ps). They let you view heatmaps for your app, and other interaction data.

Example heatmap:

[image: heatmap example image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at [Appsee](http://www.appsee.com)

Appsee provides visual in-app analytics, including heatmaps, real user recording and user bahavior reprots. And you can create a free account there.

Answer (score 0):

Flurry, Google Analytics, etc are central server to store the user's data. 
If you want to build your private data center. you can visit this url
 **http://www.github.com/cobub**
And the web site is: **http://dev.cobub.com**

to get the open source system (both server and client sides)

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of analytics: business analytics and app performance analytics. Google Analtyics, Flurry etc are good for business analytics but app developers are mostly interested in knowing when app crashes, being able to capture app logs, impact of network speeds and carriers on performance of their apps. For app performance analytics, take a look at http://apigee.com/about/mobile-analytics . You not only get real time performance anlaytics but also ability to do some configuration changes in real time.